# Probability of $k$ chickens dying simultaneously out of $n$ chickens

Tags: probability

I have $n$ chickens. Probability of 1 chicken dying is $1\over n$. What is the probability of $k$ chickens dying simultaneously. As the death is simultaneous death of one chicken does not influence the other. I have three different answers in my mind.

As they are independent events probability of one chicken dying **and** another chicken dying is $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. So $\frac{1}{n^{k}}$ can be an answer.

One chickens death changes the population by $n-1$ so probability decreses $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. But here the events are simultaneous. Also decresing probability decreses probability of death then probability a single chicken dying is $1$.

On the other hand there can be $k$ different combinations out of $n$ chickens. So simultaneous death of k chickens accounts for the complete death of one such combination. So the answer can be $\frac{1}{n\choose k}$. But When one combination dies completely there are some other combinations that die partially.

What is the correct answer ?

Comment: You don't really mean "simultaneously."  That would presumably be 0 (ignoring possibilities like a bomb hitting the henhouse.)  Probably you mean something like "dying the same day."  You may want a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Well actually these chickens are resources that may die out of battery. And that may happen in a given time t. But I think dying within a fixed time span $t_{s} \rightarrow t_{e}$ should also work.

Comment: Maybe a Poisson process?  Why would one resource dying change the probability of another resource's death?  If this is really so, then the process doesn't satisfy the axioms for either a binomial distribution or a Poisson process.  I've been assuming you made a mistake in the math, and that it's not really true of the problem, but of course, I could be wrong.